# Found 2 wires hanging below shingles against foundation

Tags: electrical

I found 2 wires hanging below the shingles against the foundation outside my house under my bedroom window. One is white, the other black. Are they electrical? No idea how long they've been there and now I'm scared. I accidentally touched them when pushing leaves away with my hand and I didn't get electrocuted. They were hidden by the leaves. Please answer asap; it's going to rain tomorrow![image]

Comment: has it ever rained in the past? possibly they are  control wires for a sprinkler system, can you post a photo? (with a ruler so we can see size)

Comment: This house does not have a sprinkler system. It has wooden shingles, not vinyl siding, and these 2 wires are hanging from behind the shingles. It's too dark to take a pic right now. I don't know how long they've been dangling...I don't know if me moving the leaves pulled them outside, that's why I'm afraid of the rain...

Comment: If the wires are outside and you're inside you'll be OK if it rains.  I'm guessing it's an old telephone cable.  How long have you lived there?

Comment: We need to know where in the world you are! A photo may be helpful. Wire color codes are different in different parts of the world. White and blue are the same thing in different areas of the world, in the us white might be neutral , but would not be be left open to touch in any case or ether side of the pond!

Comment: I'm in Rhode Island, in the USA.

Comment: I added a pic! I was wrong, it's a white wire and a black one, and they aren't just hanging, they go right into the ground, which I hadn't noticed yesterday. They're very stiff wires. I guess if they go into the ground, they're supposed to be there? Should I cover them with anything for protection?

Comment: Is there a detached garage nearby or perhaps a light over a basketball court?  Maybe someone, at one time, ran power to an external fixture/building.

Comment: No, Steve, nothing at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102698/discussion-on-question-by-rose-found-2-wires-hanging-below-shingles-against-foun).

Comment: Is there any indication that there is (or was previously) an "invisible" dog fence installed?

Answer (score 1):

The safest thing to do of course is turn off your main and treat it as an emergency, make an emergency call to a licensed electrician.  Nobody could rule out from what's provided that these wires are unsafe.

My personal opinion, it's such a remote chance that this is an imminent danger, I'd have someone that's competent to work on basic wiring check it as soon as possible, but I wouldn't make it an emergency service call to an electrician.

With no bare conductor exposed, there's really nothing DIY for you to do.

There's a real chance these wires are just some scrap that got buried.

If they are connected to your electrical system, it's obviously not code compliant;  but then again it must have been there for a long time, so it's not likely there's anything that's going to happen today.

Again I am not assuring you there's no hazard, just saying what I would do if I were in your shoes.

Comment: Batsplasterson, are you an electrician? Have you ever seen this before?